# Every query on SQLite DB using EF Core in Docker is very slow, unless there is an explicit call to OpenConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, docker, .net-core

I am running a simple .NET Core 3.1 web application on localhost. The web application is running in a Docker Linux container (my host OS is Windows 10). The SQLite database used by the web application is connected using EF Core, is almost empty and very small at 60Kb, each table having 20 records or less, and is stored on the host and mounted for the container using following command:

```
--mount type=bind,source='SomeDummyHostPath',target=/mnt/hostFolder
```

The problem is that every query executed on DBContext runs very slow (~2s for reading 2 rows). When I run the application outside of the Docker container, everything runs smoothly (meaning that the same query is executed in ~1ms).

What is strange is, after invoking `dbContext.Database.OpenConnectionAsync()` before every call to EF's DBSets, every query in the Docker container runs quickly (a few milliseconds).

Why is the performance so bad in this scenario? Is there any way to improve it without the explicit call to `OpenConnectionAsync` before every query?

Comment: Are you using passwords or encryption perhaps? SQLite is an *embedded* database, which means it's run by your own application. Every connection is essentially just a file open, which *shouldn't* be expensive unless encryption, or *really* slow storage is involved. Which EF, SQLite drivers and versions are you using? There were similar questions in the past, and [an EF Core issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13837) about the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite driver

Comment: `a Docker Linux container (my host OS is Windows 10)` on which file system is the database stored? Have you tried running the app in WSL2? The delay may be caused by  the IO operation translation between Linux and Windows. That was one of the main reasons WSL2 was created. I suspect if you run your app in WSL2 you won't notice a delay

Comment: BTW new versions of Docker [use WSL2 as the Linux backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/). You need to perform a few configuration steps though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core 3.x included one breaking change that affects this use-case, the connection is closed earlier:

> Database connection is now closed if not used anymore before the
> TransactionScope has been completed

**Mitigations:**

> If the connection needs to remain open explicit call to
> OpenConnection() will ensure that EF Core doesn't close it
> prematurely

The sqlite provider is **still not using connection pooling**: [13837](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13837);

With the new releases of EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (>3.0), there are some new optimizations regarding transactionality, and new .WAL file is created when the .db file is open; This, combined with lack of connection pooling results in creating and removing the .WAL file with every request; And docker volume/file mapping to windows file system gets to be very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much more to explain than what Lucian has already done in the accepted answer. Anyway, I will restate to contextualize the link.

The problem is all about EF Core closing and reopening the connection every statement.

One way to work around this is providing the connection (already open) by yourself. EF does not auto close connections that were already open.

As he also stated, at the time of this answer, the connection provider for SQLite still don't use a connection pool.

The best way to achieve the maximum performance with EF Core and SQLite is to provide a connection pool. The goal of the pool is maintaining some connections always open, because the problem itself is the overhead of opening new connections.

Finally, the link is a comment that I've made in the EF Core GitHub issue tracker containing a complete example of how to do that in a simple way.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13837#issuecomment-821717602